# System-wide socks5 proxy

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, tor

I am trying to get my server to run entirely through TOR proxy settings.

I have TOR installed it works when I do it from Mint's GUI by setting the socks host to `127.0.0.1:9050`.

That way, all my traffic is tunnelled through TOR. How do I do this via command-line?

Comment: This is not the correct solution to get *your server to run entirely through Tor*.  Using Tor as a transparent proxy requires more work, you should read here, https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Maybe I said it wrong. I want all outbound traffic to be used with TOR like Mint does it. I want the same exact thing but using cli

Comment: Thats' exactly what I understood. You should read the page I referenced.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae This seems far more complicated than it should be. Mint manages to do that with a click of a button (almost a click) and very easy to toggle. That doesn't seem like it will be as easy to manage.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me you know better than the authors of Tor how to convey all of your traffic thru Tor?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae When did I say that?? I just want to find the commands that are run to allow Mint do it the way it does. Editing torrc is not what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the GUI is configured via GSettings under `org.gnome.system.proxy`.

See all available keys and their values:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy
```

Set specific values as per your example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '127.0.0.1'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 9050
```

Be aware, though, that it doesn't force all apps to use proxy, this is just a recommendation that an application might ignore. For example, by default Firefox is configured to honor system proxy, but you may go to settings and change "Use system proxy settings" to "No proxy".

Answer (score -1):

You can [use Torghost.](https://github.com/susmithHCK/torghost)

Regards,

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.